# libsass bindings not found. Try reinstalling node-sass?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, mongodb, cordova

Im trying to create an offline app following this tutorial here:

http://rafaelquintanilha.com/offline-app-with-meteor-and-cordova/

But whenever I get to the:

```
 meteor run android-device
```

I get an error:

> => Started proxy.
>   => Started MongoDB.
>   => Errors prevented startup:
>          While loading plugin `compileScss` from package `fourseven:scss`:
>
> /home/bryam/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.2.1.1.1l0pytj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScss.os.linux.x86_64/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScss/compileScss/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:22:11:
>   `libsass` bindings not found. Try reinstalling `node-sass`?    at
>   getBinding
>   (/home/bryam/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.2.1.1.1l0pytj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScss.os.linux.x86_64/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScss/compileScss/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:22:11)
>   at Object.
>   (/home/bryam/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.2.1.1.1l0pytj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileScss.os.linux.x86_64/npm/node_modules/meteor/compileScss/compileScss/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:188:23)
>   at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)    at
>   Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)    at Module.load
>   (module.js:343:32)    at Module.Mp.load
>   (/home/bryam/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.0-1.13j49n2++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/reify/node/runtime.js:16:23)
>   at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)    at Module.require
>   (module.js:353:17)    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)    at
>   Object. (/tools/isobuild/bundler.js:1565:22)    at
>   Object.require (/tools/isobuild/bundler.js:1542:11)    at
>   packages/compileScss/plugin/compile-scss.js:2:1    at
>   :151:4    at :158:3
>
> => Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.

I have tried everything that I found on google and I still keep getting the same error, somebody know how to fix this?

Comment: What if you get the 2.1.1 fourseven version? https://github.com/fourseven/meteor-scss/issues/95

Comment: Ill give it a try thanks for suggesting.